# Is there something wrong with this sites statistics?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Is there something wrong with this sites statistics?

[This is a question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3342/my-brickwall-with-a-possible-lead-however-with-discrepencies/3343?noredirect=1#3343) I asked yesterday, it states it has been viewed 3 times, yet there are  6 votes.  If you see different maybe there is something wrong with my computers cache.

Comment: I spend a lot of time on other stack sites and this is quite unique to this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has come up a few times on Meta Stack Overflow. The explanation seems to be (1) the views counter is approximated, but votes are not; (2) there's caching involved so updating the views counter isn't done instantly; and (3) the views counter depends on unique IP addresses so multiple accounts sharing an IP address will only show up as a single view.

So I doubt it's a bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is primarily due to database caching where some of the information displayed (such as the number of views on a post) is stored locally rather than checking the database each time for the latest up-to-date number. It's a performance enhancement that generally works well across all sites, but this side effect is much more pronounced when a site has less traffic. It will hardly be noticed once the site starts humming along.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same on my questions lately. A question might have four votes, but say that it's been viewed twice. This didn't use to be the case. I do think you've found a bug :)